# Handling SIGCHLD NASM

Tags: segmentation-fault, nasm, x86-64

**EDIT** See my self answer below

---

I've been trying to replicate this C program in NASM

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void handle(int sig) {
    int status;
    wait(&status);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct sigaction act;
    bzero(&act, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = &handle;
    sigaction(SIGCLD, &act, NULL);
    pid_t pid;
    if ( (pid = fork()) == 0) {
        printf("message from child\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("message from parent\n");
    pause();
    exit(0);
}
```

My NASM code looks like this:

```
USE64

STRUC sigact
    .handler        resq 1
    .mask           resq 16
    .flag           resd 1
    .restorer       resq 1
    .pad            resb 4
ENDSTRUC

section .text
global _start
_start:
    ; register SIGCHLD handler
    mov     rdi, act
    mov     rsi, sigact_size
    call    bzero
    mov     QWORD [act], handle
    ; still need to figure out what these mean
    ; yanked out of gdb right before the same syscall
    ; and the act struct had these set :\
    mov     QWORD [act+8], 0x4000000
    mov     DWORD [act+16], 0xf7a434a0
    mov     DWORD [act+20], 0x7fff
    mov     rax, 13
    mov     rdi, 17
    lea     rsi, [act]
    mov     rdx, 0x0
    mov     r10, 0x8
    syscall
    cmp     rax, 0
    jne     sigaction_fail
    mov     rax, 57
    syscall
    cmp     rax, 0
    je      child
    mov     rax, parentmsg
    call    print
    mov     rax, 34
    syscall
    mov     rax, parentexit
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall


sigaction_fail:
    enter   0, 0
    mov     rax, safailed
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, -1
    syscall

handle:
    enter   0x10, 0
    push    rax
    push    rsi
    push    rdi
    push    rdx
    push    r10
    lea     rsi, [rbp-0x10]
    mov     rax, 61
    mov     rdi, -1
    xor     rdx, rdx
    xor     r10, r10
    syscall
    cmp     rax, -1
    jne     .handle_success
    mov     rax, hdfailed
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, -1
    syscall
.handle_success:
    mov     rax, hdsuccess
    call    print
    pop     r10
    pop     rdx
    pop     rdi
    pop     rsi
    pop     rax
    leave
    ret

child:
    mov     rax, childmsg
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall

; print a null terminated string stored in rax
print:
    enter   0, 0
    push    rbx
    push    rdx
    push    rdi
    push    rsi
    mov     rbx, rax
    call    strlen
    mov     rdx, rax
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1 ; stdout
    mov     rsi, rbx
    syscall
    pop     rsi
    pop     rdi
    pop     rdx
    pop     rbx
    leave
    ret

bzero:
    ; rdi pointer to uint8_t
    ; uint32_t rsi length
    enter   0, 0
    mov     rcx, rsi
    dec     rcx ; err..
.bzeroloop:
    lea     rax, [rdi + rcx]
    xor     rax, rax
    cmp     rcx, 0
    je      .bzerodone
    dec     rcx
    jmp     .bzeroloop
.bzerodone:
    leave
    ret

strlen:
    enter   0, 0
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rax
.strlen_countchar:
    cmp     BYTE [rax], 0 ; compare it to null byte
    jz      .strlen_exit
    inc     rax
    jmp     .strlen_countchar
.strlen_exit:
    sub     rax, rbx
    pop     rbx
    leave
    ret



section .data
    childmsg:   db  "from child", 0xa, 0 ; null terminated
    parentmsg   db  "from parent", 0xa, 0
    handlemsg   db  "in handle", 0xa, 0
    safailed    db  "failed to set signal handler", 0xa, 0
    hdfailed    db  "failed waiting for child", 0xa, 0
    hdsuccess   db  "successfully waited on child", 0xa, 0
    parentexit  db  "parent exiting", 0xa, 0

section .bss
    act:            resb    sigact_size
    status:         resq    1
```

It successfully waits on the child when the signal is sent, but immediately seg faults on return. I've tried reading more and more on signals and signal handling but at this point it is all running together as mush in my head. Sorry of the NASM code is ugly or nonstandard. Not only am I learning, but I've probably rewritten each part at least 25 times (maybe 100+ times for `handle`).

Comment: Did you look at gcc's asm output for `handle`?  It's [pretty simple](https://godbolt.org/g/qblpF7).  Also, never use the `enter` instruction.  It's horribly slow.  (See Agner Fog's guide, linked from the [x86 tag wiki](https://godbolt.org/g/qblpF7).)

Comment: Also, did you use a debugger to see which instruction actually faults, and check that `rsp` is correct (i.e. pointing to the return address, like it was on function entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooooook after a long time poking I finally figured this out! The problem was setting the restorer correctly in the sigact struct.

When I checked `sigaction(2)` to get the struct definition it ended up not being what I thought it was at all. I got this:

```
struct sigaction {
    void     (*sa_handler)(int);
    void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    sigset_t   sa_mask;
    int        sa_flags;
    void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
};
```

but that is the C definition of the struct (well not quite, as the man page mentions the first two might be a union which was the case for me).

However some more poking around I found that the struct that I needed to build looks more like this:

```
struct asm_sigaction {
    void                  (*sa_handler)(int);
    [unsigned?] long      sa_flags;
    void                  (*sa restorer)(void);
    sigset_t              sa_mask; 
};
```

I found this out by digging around in what my C code was really doing. I found the spot where the same syscall that I was making was made and dumped the bytes for what they were passing for the sigaction struct:

```
(gdb) x/38wx $rsi
0x7fffffffddc0: 0x004007f5  0x00000000  0x14000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffddd0: 0xf7a434a0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffdde0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffddf0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffde00: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffde10: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffde20: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffde30: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffde40: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

The part at `0x7fffffffddd0` looked like an address to me so I checked it out:

```
(gdb) disas 0x00007ffff7a434a0
Dump of assembler code for function __restore_rt:
   0x00007ffff7a434a0 <+0>: mov    rax,0xf
   0x00007ffff7a434a7 <+7>: syscall 
   0x00007ffff7a434a9 <+9>: nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
```

Sure enough they were setting the restorer which was calling `sigreturn` (in my case `rt_sigreturn`) system call! The man page said applications don't normally mess with that, but that is for typical C programs I guess. So I went ahead and copied this function in the restorer label and put it in the appropriate spot in my struc and wooooooo it worked.

Here is the now working NASM, I changed things around a bit with a new C program which I tried to make look and act more like my NASM program was and switched out `pause` for `nanosleep`.

New C program:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

const char *parentmsg = "from parent\n\0";
const char *childmsg = "from child\n\0";
const char *handlemsg = "in handle\n\0";
const char *forkfailed = "fork failed\n\0";
const char *parentexit = "parent exiting\n\0";
const char *sleepfailed = "sleep failed\n\0";
const char *sleepinterrupted = "sleep interrupted\n\0";

void print(const char *msg) {
    write(STDIN_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
}

static void handle(int sig) {
    print(handlemsg);
    waitid(P_ALL, -1, NULL, WEXITED|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct timespec tsreq;
    struct timespec tsrem;
    tsreq.tv_sec = 2;
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = &handle;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL);
    pid_t pid;
    if ( (pid = fork()) == 0 ) {
        print(childmsg);
        exit(0);
    }
    print(parentmsg);
    if (nanosleep((const struct timespec*)&tsreq, &tsrem) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            print(sleepinterrupted);
            nanosleep((const struct timespec*)&tsrem, NULL);
        } else {
            print(sleepfailed);
        }
    }
    print(parentexit);
    exit(0);
}
```

And the new working NASM (with some help from Peter to hopefully make it look and function little better)

```
USE64

STRUC sigact
    .handler        resq 1
    .flag           resq 1
    .restorer       resq 1
    .mask           resq 16
ENDSTRUC

STRUC timespec
    .tv_sec         resq 1
    .tv.nsec        resq 1
ENDSTRUC

section .text
global _start
_start:
    ; register SIGCHLD handler
    mov     DWORD [act+sigact.handler], handle
    mov     QWORD [act+sigact.restorer], restorer
    mov     DWORD [act+sigact.flag], 0x04000000
    mov     rax, 13
    mov     rdi, 17
    lea     rsi, [act]
    xor     rdx, rdx
    mov     r10, 0x8
    syscall
    cmp     eax, 0
    jne     sigaction_fail
    mov     rax, 57
    syscall
    cmp     eax, -1
    je      fork_failed
    cmp     eax, 0
    je      child
    mov     rax, parentmsg
    call    print
    mov     rax, 35
    mov     QWORD [tsreq+timespec.tv_sec], 2
    lea     rdi, [tsreq]
    lea     rsi, [tsrem]
    syscall
    cmp     eax, -1
    je      .exit
    mov     rax, sleepagain
    call    print
    mov     rax, 35
    mov     rdi, tsrem
    xor     rsi, rsi
    syscall
.exit:
    mov     rax, parentexit
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    xor     rdi, rdi
    syscall


restorer:
    mov     rax, 15
    syscall

fork_failed:
    mov     rax, forkfailed
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, -1
    syscall

sigaction_fail:
    mov     rax, safailed
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, -1
    syscall

handle:
    mov     rax, handlemsg
    call    print
    lea     rsi, [rsp-0x4]
    mov     rax, 247
    xor     rdi, rdi
    xor     rdx, rdx
    mov     r10, 14
    syscall
    cmp     eax, -1
    jne     .success
    mov     rax, hdfailed
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, -1
    syscall
.success:
    mov     rax, hdsuccess
    call    print
    ret

child:
    mov     rax, childmsg
    call    print
    mov     rax, 60
    xor     rdi, rdi
    syscall

; print a null terminated string stored in rax
print:
    push    rbx
    push    rdx
    push    rdi
    push    rsi
    mov     rbx, rax
    call    strlen
    mov     rdx, rax
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1 ; stdout
    mov     rsi, rbx
    syscall
    pop     rsi
    pop     rdi
    pop     rdx
    pop     rbx
    ret

strlen:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rax
.countchar:
    cmp     BYTE [rax], 0 ; compare it to null byte
    jz      .exit
    inc     rax
    jmp     .countchar
.exit:
    sub     rax, rbx
    pop     rbx
    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret



section .data
    childmsg:   db  "from child", 0xa, 0 ; null terminated
    parentmsg   db  "from parent", 0xa, 0
    handlemsg   db  "in handle", 0xa, 0
    safailed    db  "failed to set signal handler", 0xa, 0
    hdfailed    db  "failed waiting for child", 0xa, 0
    hdsuccess   db  "successfully waited on child", 0xa, 0
    parentexit  db  "parent exiting", 0xa, 0
    forkfailed  db  "fork failed", 0xa, 0
    sleepagain  db  "sleeping again", 0xa, 0

section .bss
    tsreq:          resb    timespec_size
    tsrem:          resb    timespec_size
    act:            resb    sigact_size
```

Comment: You don't need to call `bzero`: act is in the bss so it's already all-zero.  And if you want to avoid libc wrappers for system calls, you might as well us `rep stosq` like gcc does when it compiles your function.  Nice digging to find the asm struct; I had started to look at the code with gdb, but didn't finish.  I was still thinking that glibc's `sigaction` wrapper around `rt_sigaction` was adding extra signals to the mask :P

Comment: That is what I thought too! That is why I just copied them originally as you can see in the comment in the original. Didn't know about the bzero either, will remove

Comment: BTW, yes the "*applications don't normally mess with that*" wording applies to programs that use the API provided by glibc, not the underlying system calls directly.  This is one of many cases where the glibc wrapper does something extra between the POSIX interface and the Linux system-call interface.  It's not always well-documented in the man pages, but at least glibc is Free software so you can look at [its source code (with comments)](https://www.sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=summary).

Answer (score 2):

Signal handlers are normal functions.  Return with `ret`, not `iret`.  (You've since edited your question to fix this, so I guess you're having other problems).

Look at how gcc compiles `handler()`, on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3++-fno-tree-vectorize',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOID2A6ACwD4AoUSWRVTOKEAI0NPOnmXQwCdwBzJs8KyroQPMAEMo/FpXYwwIGtMGzqATzQB6AO7iQGfiUziMICEgBuOEHCQFxYWggAU4DEjSiAlEgDeJJECkNw8MExg0AG4AoN19ZwAyYwwIr2iAXxISEIBbPTBnKxsffyDQzhgId08ecSrcMCQ6jGiy%2BgAvBE4cROaAGg8QTpwAM2dmrzSYwOa8NHEAfXtHKC6kAF4kBOWnVqCa5obnAGUASQBxAGEAGQARAYT%2BpAA5AFVr66mygAcbBfdfnA9oEQCMkM5wYCNkgRjhOABrZyTDabAAMJWmZSQ324YAwYwARDkEGh5jxkCNujkkBACCAoHAADpgAlfLGBBAAD3i6OBSEyP1x%2BOcRJJZIpVOx4k4CDxzNZfO%2B4giLjZHO5GGcvJI6SAAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

```c
static void handle(int sig) {
    int status;
    wait(&status);
}
```

```asm
    sub     rsp, 24
    xor     eax, eax           # you forgot to include sys/wait.h, so the compiler has no prototype for wait(), so has to follow the ABI for variadic functions (al = number of FP args in xmm regs)
    lea     rdi, [rsp+12]
    call    wait
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
```

---

It's not hard to turn the library call into an inline invocation of `wait4(2)`.

Note that the man page says `wait4` is obsolete, and new programs should use [`waitpid` or `waitid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).  However, if you don't need any more functionality, `wait4` is fine.  glibc implements `wait(3)` on top of the `wait4` Linux system call, not `waitid`.  If there was anything wrong with using `wait4`, glibc would use `waitid` directly.

```
handle:
    mov     eax, 61          ; __NR_wait4 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h
    mov     edi, -1          ; pid_t is a 32bit type, so we don't need to sign-extend into rdi.
    lea     rsi, [rsp-4]     ; status = a pointer into the red zone below rsp.
    xor     edx,edx          ; options = 0
    xor     r10d,r10d        ; rusage = NULL
    syscall
    ; eax = pid waited for, or -1 to indicate error
    ; dword [rsp-4] = status.  unlike function calls, syscalls don't clobber the stack
    ret
```

To use the return values from `wait4`, do something like:

```
    cmp     rax, -1         ;;;; THIS WAS A BUG: pid_t is a 32bit type; expect garbage or zeros in the upper 32 bits.

    cmp     eax, -1
    je   .error
    ...
```

Set a breakpoint in `handle` if you want to debug it.  That's *much* easier than using debug-prints in asm.

If this still crashes when you `ret`, maybe it's returning successfully but actually crashing in your main program.  Use a debugger to find out.

---

Your string constants should go in the `.rodata` section.  You don't need to modify them at runtime, so don't put them in `.data`.

You also don't need to `call bzero`, since your `act` is in the bss.  If you wanted to allocate it on the stack, instead of statically, you should zero it with `rep stosq` like gcc 5.3 does in your `main()`.  (It inlines bzero, [as you can see on Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3++-fno-tree-vectorize',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOID2A6ACwD4AoUSWRVTOKEAI0NPOnmXQwCdwBzJs8KyroQPMAEMo/FpXYwwIGtMGzqATzQB6AO7iQGfiUziMICEgBuOEHCQFxYWggAU4DEjSiAlEgDeJJECkNw8MExg0AG4AoN19ZwAyYwwIr2iAXxISEIBbPTBnKxsffyDQzhgId08ecSrcMCQ6jGiy%2BgAvBE4cROaAGg8QTpwAM2dmrzSYwOa8NHEAfXtHKC6kAF4kBOWnVqCa5obnAGUASQBxAGEAGQARAYT%2BpAA5AFVr66mygAcbBfdfnA9oEQCMkM5wYCNkgRjhOABrZyTDabAAMJWmZSQ324YAwYwARDkEGh5jxkCNujkkBACCAoHAADpgAlfLGBBAAD3i6OBSEyP1x%2BOcRJJZIpVOx4k4CDxzNZfO%2B4giLjZHO5GGcvJI6SAAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)).

---

BTW, your NASM struct in the question has the padding in the wrong place.  Probably worth noting for your future adventures, even though it turns out not to be part of the answer to this question.  (Your code wasn't even using the NASM struct syntax after you defined it.)

The actual `struct sigaction` is defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigaction.h`, as you can find out from searching for it in `echo '#include <signal.h>' | gcc -E - | less`.

```
struct sigaction {
    union {
      __sighandler_t sa_handler;    // your code uses this one, because it leaves SA_SIGINFO unset in sa_flags
      void (*sa_sigaction) (int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    };  // with some macros to sort this out
    __sigset_t sa_mask;   // 1024 bits = 128B
    int sa_flags; 
    void (*sa_restorer) (void);
};
```

Your NASM struct has the padding in the wrong place:

```
STRUC sigact
    .handler        resq 1    ; 64bit pointer: correct
    .mask           resq 16   ; 16 qwords for sigset_t: correct, it's 128 bytes
    .flag           resd 1    ; 32bit flags: correct
    ;; The padding goes here, to align the 64bit member that follows
    .pad            resb 4
    .restorer       resq 1    ; 64bit
    ;; There's no padding here
ENDSTRUC
```

Comment: Hey peter, that `iret` is just another iteration that I tried. I was also returning with `ret`. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Also I don't have the wait function available to me so I do it with the syscall for `wait4(2)` which is why mine looks so different than that one (and I started going crazy preserving registers on the stack cause I thought maybe I was destroying them or something)

Comment: @user3591723: I updated my answer with a `handler` that doesn't use any library functions.  Don't use debug-prints in asm, that's what a debugger like gdb is for.  I didn't look at your asm `_start` to see if you install the signal handler correctly, and I didn't check your asm `handler` very carefully.  If you actually crash on `ret`, maybe you broke the stack.  Like I said, use a debugger to check for that.

Comment: Yea I've been using the debugger. I missed the part where it says it is obsolete in the man page. I was using it because I only have waitid and wait4 on my system and wait4 was less complicated ;)

I've been using gdb to debug my code, but on this problem I couldn't quite figure it out even with gdb. I'm still learning both gdb and NASM so I could be missing a few things. I'm going to go at it today with a fresher head and will maybe update my question. The prints are there just because I didn't want silence. I was getting lonely.

Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @user3591723: Even though `wait` / `wait4` are apparently "obsolete", they're not going away any time soon.  If there was anything wrong with using `wait4`, glibc would implement `wait(3)` on top of `waitid(2)` instead of `wait4(2)`.

Comment: Hey Peter thanks for your help. I ended up hunting down the problem. I wrote up an answer explaining where I was messing up.

Comment: @user3591723: I just saved some edits that I had started before you posted your answer.

Comment: Good stuff. Never knew about piping gcc with the -E flag like that. I was just using `find` and then checking the many files.

Comment: @user3591723: If I don't know what file to look in, I use `grep -r something /usr/include /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.  Or better, `ack something /usr/include /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.  I forget exactly what extra checking `ack` does to avoid wasting time searching binary files.  grep may default to skipping binary files too, but not based on file extension.  But anyway, I don't usually bother with `find /path -name '*.h' -exec grep something {} +`